# speed accuracy - best practice

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I would like to get the most accurate & updated with highest frequency speed I can get. I display speed & accuracy in label.text

Therefore I use `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

and check for (the lower the better)

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    gpsAccuracyHorizontal = String(location.horizontalAccuracy)
}
```

But I am wondering if there is any better solution. Not even 100% sure if .horizontalAccuracy is even relevant for speed or only for latitude and longitude?

Comment: wuhuuu I earned the Tumbleweed badge would give it away for free if somebody could help me out here :-D